# Makefile: wildcard and patsubst does not change file source names

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to write a Makefile for my project, all the `*.c` and `*.h` files are in a folder called `src`, and the Makefile looks like this --

```
CC              := gcc
CFLAGS          := -g -Wall -ansi -pedantic -std=gnu99
LDFLAGS         := -lm 
INCLUDES        := $(wildcard src/*.h)
IFLAGS          := $(addprefix -I/,$(INCLUDES))
SRC             := $(wildcard src/*.c)
OBJS            := $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRC))
APP             := app

all: $(OBJS)

$(APP): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(OBJS): $(SRC) $(INCLUDES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(IFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJS)
    rm -rf *.out
    rm -f $(APP)
```

At this point I am not building the executable, just trying to compile them to object files, so when I run, I am getting this output --

```
gcc -g -Wall -ansi -pedantic -std=gnu99 -I/src/structure.h -I/src/rng.h -c src/allocate.c -o src/allocate.o
gcc -g -Wall -ansi -pedantic -std=gnu99 -I/src/structure.h -I/src/rng.h -c src/allocate.c -o src/auxiliary.o
gcc -g -Wall -ansi -pedantic -std=gnu99 -I/src/structure.h -I/src/rng.h -c src/allocate.c -o src/decode.o
gcc -g -Wall -ansi -pedantic -std=gnu99 -I/src/structure.h -I/src/rng.h -c src/allocate.c -o src/display.o
```

You can see that in each `gcc` invocation, the source file names do not change, they are all always `src/allocate.c` why ? However, the object names are correctly expanded like `src/allocate.o`, `src/auxiliary.o` and `src/decode.o`etc.

Comment: the targets 'clean' and 'all' are phony targets because no file with those names will be generated.  Therefore there needs to be a line, before the first of those targets,:  '.PHONY: clean all'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you've mixed up some things here.

They are basically two type of rules you need to use here, and they both share the same syntax:

```
target(s): prerequisite(s)
    recipe
```

When you write this:

```make
$(APP): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

You're saying to make that you want to create `$(APP)`, and to do that you need `$(OBJS)` to exist or to be created.

Now when you write this:

```make
$(OBJS): $(SRC) $(INCLUDES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(IFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

You're telling make you want to create a list of `.o` files, and for each individual file that you need all `$(SRC)` and `$(INCLUDES)`.

Since in the recipe you're using `$<`, which is a shortcut for **the first entry in the prerequisites list**, you always end up with the same source file being compiled.

---

To do what you want, you must abstract things a little bit and tell make "Here is how I want you to build **any** `.o` file that depends on a corresponding `.c`". That is the job of pattern rules:

```make
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

Ultimately, your Makefile should look like this:

```make
APP    := app
SRC    := $(wildcard src/*.c)
OBJ    := $(SRC:.c=.o)
CFLAGS := -W -Wall -g -std=c99 -pedantic
LDLIBS := -lm

all: $(OBJS)

$(APP): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(APP) $(OBJ)
```

Note another couple of things here that you missed:

- The `-I` *preprocessor* flag (that should be placed in the `CPPFLAGS` variable) accepts a **directory**, not a file.
- The `-ansi` compiler flag is a synonym of `-std=c89`. You're using `-std=gnu99` right after so that one will be picked ultimately
- You don't need to list your header files at all. Don't bother.
- Don't use the `-r` flag of the `rm` command without care, you'll end up removing folders. It is not used to remove multiple files but to remove recursively, read up your man.
- You used `$<` instead of `$^` at the linking phase, so your executable will miss many object files.

---

To address the comments:

GNU make has a lot of predefined rules, functions and variables that you should be using before rolling your own. It has basic rules for compiling and linking C and C++ programs, amongst many other, this is why your Makefile does not need to redefine the `%.o: %c` rule that already exists.

You can see all of these by typing this in your favorite shell:

```bash
make -p
```

`$(RM)`, `$(CC)` are one of these predefined variables, you can see by yourself what they actually contain.

Now, as many users are concerned with header files dependencies, let's address this issue. You won't have to manually do that, modern compilers like GCC and Clang do this for you once you set them up.

The dependencies for each `.c` file will be generated in a `.d` file that must be included in the Makefile.

To tell the compiler to generate these files while compiling, you need to pass a preprocessor flag:

```make
CPPFLAGS := -MMD
```

Now the dependencies are auto-generated, we need to include them:

```make
DEP := $(OBJ:.o=.d)

-include $(DEP)
```

You'd also want to clean them:

```make
clean:
    $(RM) $(APP) $(OBJ) $(DEP)
```

Now your Makefile looks like this:

```make
APP      := app
SRC      := $(wildcard src/*.c)
OBJ      := $(SRC:.c=.o)
DEP      := $(OBJ:.o=.d)
CPPFLAGS := -MMD
CFLAGS   := -W -Wall -g -std=c99 -pedantic
LDLIBS   := -lm

all: $(OBJS)

$(APP): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(APP) $(OBJ) $(DEP)

-include $(DEP)
```

Last point: the syntax `$(SRC:.c=.o)` is a shortcut for `$(SRC:%.c=%.o)` which is also a shortcut for `$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC))`.

Comment: This solution does not rebuild the object files if a relevant header file is modified.   To do this, add `-MP` and `-MD` to your CFLAGS, along with a `-include $(SRC:%.c=%.d)` line in the main makefile (see http://www.microhowto.info/howto/automatically_generate_makefile_dependencies.html for details)

Comment: Considering the OP's actual knowledge, I chose to not talk about that since it is not really part of the question. And as a side note, one should use `-MMD` instead of `-MD`.

Comment: thanks for a detailed answer, I have also some questions, 1. why there is no rule to make `$(OBJ)` in your make ? is it automatically inferred from `OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)`? 2. what is `$(RM)` ? 3. In which way `$(wildcard src/*.c), $(patsubst %c, %o, $(SRC))` and `$(SRC:.c=.o)` different?

Comment: 1) the rule does need to list all the include files when compiling, otherwise the source file will not be re-compiled when a header file changes.

Comment: See my (long) addendum guys.